# Solving complex trig quations - missing solutions?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, trigonometry

```
{
    Sin[Pi/2 + I*Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]],
    Sin[Pi/2 - I*Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]],
    Sin[Pi/2 + I*Log[2 - Sqrt[3]]],
    Sin[Pi/2 - I*Log[2 - Sqrt[3]]]
} // FullSimplify
```

These will verify to the correct answers,

> {2, 2, 2, 2}

So I am hoping to solve this using

```
Solve[Sin[z] == 2, z, Complexes] // ComplexExpand
Solve[{Sin[z] == 2, Abs[z] < 10}, z] // ComplexExpand
Solve[{Sin[z] == 2, 0 < Re[z] < 10}, z] // ComplexExpand
```

none gives the answer that has $i\log(2-\sqrt{3})$, which I don't think is equivalent to $i\log(2+\sqrt{3})$ unless I am missing something ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `Log[2 - Sqrt[3]] == -Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]`.